# Which option; cx bike or mtb and road bike?

Tags: mountain-bike, road-bike, cyclocross, fitness, off-road

I've done my research and i've narrowed it down to 2 options for me

Option 1: buy a low-end cyclocross bike for $1200
or 
Option 2: buy a low-end road bike for $800 and a low-end mountain bike for $400

My budget is $1200
I want a bike that will allow to me ride on the road and on the rough trails.
Please don't suggest a touring or hybrid bike because i don't want the relaxed geometry. I want to go fast. 
I'll be using these bikes for fitness and fun, not for commuting. 
So which option would be better for me?
Would a low-end road bike be better on the road than the low-end cyclocross? 
And would a low-end mountain bike be better on the trails than the low-end cyclocross bike?

Thank you for your input

Comment: You might want to consider buying a single bike with two sets of wheels, if you don't mind the trouble of switching back and forth.

Comment: What is "Rough" and most importantly, can it be ridden on slicks or semi slicks, and how important are shocks?  What percentage of riding is road vs trails?

Comment: Do note that wanting to "go fast" (ie, no relaxed geometry) and wanting to go off-road are two incompatible criteria.

Answer (score 3):

> I want a bike that will allow to me ride on the road and on the rough trails

I guess we can't be sure what you mean by "rough trails", but if you're talking about what I call "rough trails", a CX bike just isn't going to do it.

> i don't want the relaxed geometry. I want to go fast.

Relaxed geometry and high speed often go together off-road (think DH bikes).

On the road, a $1200 CX is not going to be as good as a $800 roadie, but that's only because of the knobby tires.

I think your best option is the road-mountain combo.

If you wanted one bike to do both jobs, I think a mountain bike with ~1.75" semi-slicks would be better than a CX. Plus, that won't cost you $1200.

A side note: No matter what you end up getting, you should buy used. You'll get much more bike for your money.

Comment: A mtn bike with 1.75 slicks is not a good road bike.  You have an upright position and a shock that is only absorbing energy.   It would get killed by road bike.  And on the trail a slick is not going to handle the rough trails.

Comment: @Frisbee I'd have a mtb with slicks any day over a CX with knobbies for road use. Btw, any decent shock has a lockout.

Comment: What?  Where does a CX with knobby come into this?  A mtn with slicks (lock out or not it is heavy) will get killed by a road bike on the road.  A CX with road tires will be close to road bike on the road.   Do you ride a CX?

Comment: @Frisbee Um, a CX with knobbies is what you promote in your answer. No, I don't ride a CX, I ride a mtb with slicks.

Comment: Promote? "On the road with SAME tires going be pretty close between the $1200 CX and the $800 road".   Mtn with slicks will be dominated by CX with slicks on the road.

Comment: @Frisbee I agree, but in order for a CX bike to be worth anything off-road it's got to have knobbies. The bike that your answer recommends to OP is a knobby-tired CX. Unless you assume that he'll be switching tires every time he wants to ride trails.

Comment: WHAT?  I do NOT recommend a CX knobby.  I suggest CX wins both ways.  For mtn to be worth anything off road it has to have knobbies.   One bike is one bike.   Pick the tire - a CX dominates on the road and holds its own off road.  And the OP states they don't want relaxed position for one bike.

Answer (score 2):

First I would not characterize a $1200 CX as low end.  Yes since they are typically sold for race the starting point is around $1200.  But overall I would not call that a low end bike.  It is going to have solid frame and mid range components.

I would take $1200 CX with knobby tires on the trail over $400 mountain.  Not going to have a front shock on the CX but not going the have a very good front shock on $400 mountain and low end components.

On the road with same tires going be pretty close between the $1200 CX and the $800 road.  With knobby tires the CX is not going to be a good road bike but with knobby tires the road bike is not going to be a good road bike either.

The main difference here is with two bikes you have two different sets of tires.

I own two CX and two mountain.  I ride 3 miles to the park for some technical riding the CX kills the mountain.  Most of a technical ride is not technical and the CX dominates.  In the highly technical sections yes the CX is slower but I can typically still ride the section.  At a slow speed 5 mph versus 3 mph is still just 2 mph over short period of time.  On the road the CX has 3-5 mph advantage the whole time (even with knobby on the CX).

Comment: a front suspension is not the only diff between a CX and a mtb.

Comment: @BSOrider No kidding.  So a statement not going to have  front shock you take to mean only difference.  OP is clearly aware of the differences in general.

Answer (score 0):

Go for the 1200 CX bike.  Reasons for this I would give:

- You can swap the wheels/tyres on a CX bike and its effectively a road bike.
- With CX tyres on you can ride the majority of the off-road terrain you'll come across
- A $400 MTB is unlikely to be very good, unless you find a second hand bargain
- MTB's are terrible on road
- I've got a CX bike which I ride on-road in the winter, and would definitely recommend them

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends in large part on what type of riding you will be doing.

On the road, are you planning to join local group rides? If so, what pace do they ride? When you say "rough trails", do you mean rocky/rooty singletrack?  Or, poorly maintained gravel roads?  How much elevation is there in your area?

Personally, I would pick a cyclocross bike that has clearance for 40mm or 45mm tires.  Something like a Salsa Vaya or Warbird.  The Vaya is listed as an "adventure touring" bike, but has ample tire clearance, drop bars, and should serve well for a mix of terrain.  The Warbird is Salsa's gravel race bike.  Lighter weight, more aggressive geometry, but still enough tire clearance for moderate single-track, gravel, and pavement.  The Warbird is a bit out of you price range, but you should be able to find a 2015 on clearance, or something similar used.